# How to set the Query cache?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, redis, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a Java Spring project. This project uses redisson-hibernate-53 cache and I'm able to cache entities by using this annotation `@Cache`; however, I'm not sure how to set queries to be cached knowing that I use Spring JpaRepository and I write my queries as follows:

```
 @QueryHints(value = {@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")
                    , @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheRegion", value = "FindByNameRegion")   })
 List<Employee> findByJobRole(String jobRole);
```

I added this property :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
```

But I think I'm missing some other configuration.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the Redis server on Windows is not stable ,however the exact configurations will work fine on other OS like linux.